# Changing elements in an HTML file using javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I've been learning HTML and CSS this semester and originally started to code my project in HTML and CSS, but in order for my project to work, I had to link HTML pages to each other. It ended up making a lot of HTML pages just to change one line of text. I've been trying to get a handle on JavaScript to make my project more efficient. My HTML code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Oakwood</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=default.css>

</head>
<body>

<div id=back></div>
<div id=drdick></div>
<div id=choice></div>

<div class="typewriter">
<script src="run.js"></script>
<p id=text>While out running someone says “Hi” causing you to trip. He helps you up.</p>
</div>  

<div id=move>
<button type="button" onclick="changeThis()">Next</button>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript Looks like this:

```
var quoteIndex = 0;
var quotes = [
    "Thank you.",
    "Are you ok?",
    "Yes, I’m not normally this clumsy"
];
function changeQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
        quoteIndex = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = quotes[quoteIndex];
}


function showPic() 
{document.getElementById("drdick").src="img/drdickab.png";}

function changeThis() {
    changeQuote();
    showPic();    
}
```

when I test my code my quotes update how I want them to. My picture does not show up at all. Is there something I am missing when it comes to how HTML and Javascript interact? I have been looking through the forums to figure out what I have wrong, and I haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: ids should have quotes `id="text"`

Comment: I changed that in my HTML file. My image is still not working

Comment: Yeah I saw that it worked anyway, just made me itchy.  Your drdick div should be an `<img>` tag, divs don't know what to do with src attribute

Comment: okay. And because I'm not assigning an image in CSS, I need more than just the div tag. Do I just assign the  <img>  tag with an Id? *update* I went ahead and assigned an Id to my <img> tag and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: yep - nice job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is not displaying because you did not specify your image anywhere in your markup, and your javascript is also not enough. But try this inside your body tag:

```
<body>

<!--replace your button with this code.-->

<div id=move>
<button type="button" onclick="showMyImage();" value="Next"></button>
</div>  

<!--I assumed you will display the image just below your button, note that initially your image is hidden and displayed on button click event-->
<div>
<img id="myImage" src="img/drdickab.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>  
</div>
</body>
```

.

```
  <!--There's really no need to have multiple scripts, just one will do the job-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showMyImage(){
     document.getElementById('myImage').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```